# Can the ANN model be suitable for different number of inputs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, evolutionary-algorithm, real-time-systems

Can the ANN model be suitable for different numbers of inputs when it predicts new results? The number of inputs should be fixed for the same model? Do I have to train the data every time? Do you some models that could be adaptive for varying inputs?
Thank you so much!